# Is $S_5=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{C}^2 ;\, y=\bar{x}\, \right\}$ a subspace of $(\mathbb{C}^2,+,\bullet,\vec{0},1)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is $S_5=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{C}^2 ;\, y=\bar{x}\, \right\}$ a subspace of $(\mathbb{C}^2,+,\bullet,\vec{0},1)$

With $\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ y_1\end{pmatrix}  \dotplus \begin{pmatrix} x_2\\ y_2\end{pmatrix}:=\begin{pmatrix} x_1+x_2\\ y_1+y_2\end{pmatrix}$ that is, the usual addition in $\mathbb{C^2}$

$\lambda \bullet \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda x\\  \lambda y\end{pmatrix}$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{C}^2$

Comment: It is considered good practice to keep the body of your question self-contained. You should edit the post to include the title in the body as well.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why is $1$ part of your datum for a vector space? It seems you consider a fixed base field (namely $\Bbb C$, but within that $1$ is already uniquely determined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
**Hint:** Have you considered the effect of multiplying by a non-real complex number?